# If срабатывает при первом нажатии, после второго должен работать else, но не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery, tilda

```
    <style>
        .tn-atom .t-input-group_ph{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
     $(document).on('change','input[name="smscheck"]',function(e){
        if( $('input[name="smscheck"]').is(':checked') ){
          $('.tn-atom .t-input-group_ph').slideDown(300);
        }else{
         $('.tn-atom .t-input-group_ph').slideUp(300);
        }; 
     });
    </script>
```

есть такой код, slideDown работает при нажатии на чекбокс, а при повторном нажатии должен slideUp, но не работает. Не поможете?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код в тестовом примере, прекрасно работает. Значит в вашем вопросе недостаточно сведений, которые бы отражали ошибку. Попробуйте собрать пример, который отражал бы ошибку и так же проверьте из разных браузеров.

```js
$(document).on('change','input[name="smscheck"]',function(e){
  if( $('input[name="smscheck"]').is(':checked') ){
    $('.tn-atom .t-input-group_ph').slideDown(300);
  }else{
    $('.tn-atom .t-input-group_ph').slideUp(300);
  }; 
});
```

```css
.tn-atom .t-input-group_ph{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="smscheck" />
<div class="tn-atom">
  <div class="t-input-group_ph">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dictum diam nec velit cursus, sed sagittis nulla tincidunt. Curabitur laoreet eros a velit imperdiet euismod. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce nec dignissim dolor. Phasellus at est sit amet tortor cursus consequat. Sed accumsan porttitor nisi eget hendrerit. Etiam in ornare orci. Praesent fermentum quam nec diam eleifend egestas. Mauris faucibus, dui sit amet hendrerit posuere, quam lacus scelerisque tellus, egestas fringilla odio ante eget mi. Vestibulum vitae pellentesque lectus. Phasellus ullamcorper purus tortor, vel scelerisque metus condimentum non.
  </div>
</div>
```